# Trigger to create record from JSON object in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, triggers, jsonb, database-trigger

Concept: a trigger what creates a new record in a table after a new JSON object has been created in another table. I don't want to make any modifications yet, just to "convert" JSON objects to records with a trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_populate_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) in the trigger function, e.g.

```
create or replace function json_input_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    insert into main_table
    select *
    from jsonb_populate_record(null::main_table, new.data);
    return new;
end $$;
```

[Fully working example.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a5e36b11a8082e23d0f899208c93acfa)

Comment: I really appreciate your example. Thank you. Can I improve my question in some way?

Comment: I think your question is clear enough. But you can edit it if you want to add new aspects.

Comment: The example provided is perfect for experimentation. Thanks!